# Form fields not displayed in django html

Tags: python, django

I have written a code to make form , and i have no guess why the fields are not displayed here are my codes.

I want to get a request from the index.html page and using that request, I ran a query to display the results of the query on the same page.

```
views.py
def search123(request):
  searc=search1()
  if request.method=="POST":        
        searc=search1(request.POST or None)
        if searc.is_valid():
            if 'd_box' in request.POST:
                item_map=item.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `category_id`=%s', [request.POST['d_box']])
                lis=[]
                for e in (item_map):
                    lis.append(e.id)
                price_map=item_done.objects.filter(item_id__in=lis).order_by('item_id')
                return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts':price_map},RequestContext(request))
  return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts':searc},RequestContext(request))
```

```
index.html

<html>
<head>   
</head>

<body>
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
<h4> SEARCH </h4>
{{searc.as_table}}
<input type='submit' name="button7" value="button7">
</form>


{% regroup posts by item_id as post_list %}

<table border="4" style="width:1050px;border-collapse: collapse" >
    <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Item Codes</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>MRP</th>
            <th>Site price</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            </tr>

          </thead>        
     <tbody>           


{% for country in post_list %}

    <tr>
    <td>{{ country.grouper }}</td>
    <td>
        {% for item in country.list %}
        <div style="margin: 5px 5px">{{item.name}}</div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </td>


       <td>
        {% for item in country.list %}
        <div style="margin: 5px 5px">{{item.mrp}}</div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </td>

    <td>
        {% for item in country.list %}
        <div style="margin: 5px 5px">{{item.site_price}}</div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </td>

    <td>
        {% for item in country.list %}
        <div style="margin: 5px 5px">{{item.crawl_id}}</div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </td>


    </tr>
{% endfor %}

     </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

```
forms.py
class search1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=search
        exclude=[]
```

Comment: do you import search model in forms.py?

Comment: yup, otherwise it would have shown an error

Comment: what about answer? did you refine `searc.asatable` ? and whats your error now?

Comment: i didnt get any error earlier also, it didnt show fields on the form. Its still blank

Answer (score 0):

i think you must import `search` model in `forms.py` an also in your template you write the form name wrong ! you write `{{searc.as_table}}` it must be  `{{search.as_table}}`